rcp not found on ubuntu 24.04
I tried using rcp to transfer files from/to another machine from Ubuntu 24.04 on WLS2. However, the system cannot find rcp command. Command scp wroks fine.
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-proposed InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~$ sudo apt install openssh-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
openssh-client is already the newest version (1:9.6p1-3ubuntu13).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
Adding component(s) 'universe' to all repositories.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Hit:1 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-proposed InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Hit:1 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu noble-proposed InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~$ apt search rsh-client
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~$ rcp
Command 'rcp' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install rsh-client
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~$ sudo apt install rsh-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package rsh-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'rsh-client' has no installation candidate
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~$

I can find this page, but I'm not sure how to use/install it.
---------------- update ---------------------
I've installed rsh-client, but it still does not recognize rcp command.
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~/code/$ rcp
Command 'rcp' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install rsh-client
ubuntu@DESKTOP-D6TR:~/code/$ rsh
rsh: No host specified!
Usage: rsh [-46vn] [-l user] [-p port] [user@]host command...

Is rcp removed from rsh-client?

It doesn't look like rsh-client is available in the standard noble repositories. I suspect it has been removed as scp/rsync are more secure. Can you switch to these instead?

rsh-client (secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote machines) in Ubuntu 22.04 has been upgraded to rsh-redone-client in Ubuntu 24.04. Also rsh-server in Ubuntu 22.04 has been upgraded to rsh-redone-server in Ubuntu 24.04.
To install rsh-redone-client in Ubuntu 24.04 open the terminal and type:
sudo apt install rsh-redone-client  

Ubuntu 24.04 has phased out the older, insecure rsh utilities like rcp, including phasing it out from the rsh-redone-client package. The absence of rcp in your Ubuntu 24.04 confirms this. Ubuntu and other modern Linux distributions have largely deprecated rcp in favor of more secure alternatives like scp, which uses SSH. For more information about rsh run man rsh.

I installed rsh-redone-client, and tried rcp --help, but the system still did not recognize the command.

@user1521062 I edited my answer with my reply to your question.

There is no rcp in rsh-redone-client. It seems that new Ubuntu indeed removed rcp.

After I found this result on UbuntuUpdates, I assume it was deleted because it was insecure, but I have no idea of why the package was deleted, since there is no changelog for deleted packages.
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/noble/universe/base/rsh-client
As you already experienced, most scripts does work with scp instead of rcp, unless there is some encryption specific parameters in there.
If so, consult the documentation for scp to figure out whats wrong.
